# Does each application in a Django project has its own set of database tables? If yes, can these tables be shared?

Tags: database, django, django-models, python-2.7

Each Django app makes its own database tables
Is it possible to share these database  tables amongst various Django apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each django application haves it's own tables, which are named on your database as `application_tablename`.

You can have access and use another application's tables simply by importing their models.

For example, when you do:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User)
```

you're tying your model to another model from another application. The other model haves it's own table, and you are accessing it each time you retrieve a `Profile` model instance (if you query it's related fields) or access some property or method of any `User` instance.

Comment: I am clear with the first part of the answer but rather than using relations to instances of different entities I wish to use a single table being used by multiple apps, which might be populated by some other app. How should I configure the models in this particular case.

Comment: It would be the same as the example. Just import the model from the other application (to use in a view maybe), create an instance of it and save it. Now, if you want to use the *same table for two different models*, you could use the `db_table` meta option(although I don't see why you would want to do that).